# Why a spinning top bounces in a direction vertical to the surface that it hits?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, collision, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

When a spinning top slowly advances and hit a surface (a wall), intuitively one would expect that the top gets bounced mostly along the wall, due to the friction between the top and the wall. But the observed phenomenon is that the top gets bounced mostly in the norm direction of the wall, and in a much higher velocity than when it hits the wall.

[image: the black arrow is the direction and the spinning top approaching the wall. The red arrow is the actual direction that the top bounces, and the green arrow is the direction that I think intuitive.]